# Install xgboost under python with 32-bit msys failing

Tags: python, package, failed-installation, msys, xgboost

Trying to install xgboost is failing..? 
The version is Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit) on Windows & enterprise.
How do I proceed? I have been using R it seems its quite easy to install new package in R from RStudio, but not so in spyder as I need to go to a command-window to do it and then in this case it fails..

```
import sys

print (sys.version) 
2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages>pip install -U xgboost
Downloading/unpacking xgboost
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xgboost (from versions: 0.4a12, 0.4a13)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for xgboost
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\c_kazum\pip\pip.log


------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\c_kazum\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 08/27/15 12:52:30
Downloading/unpacking xgboost
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/
  URLs to search for versions for xgboost:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xgboost/xgboost-0.4a12.tar.gz#md5=4d768e034a28590497bb79279f036946 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/), version: 0.4a12
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xgboost/xgboost-0.4a13.tar.gz#md5=5f53d51e4305c679192b3cabda2b0dbe (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/), version: 0.4a13
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xgboost/xgboost-0.4a12.tar.gz#md5=4d768e034a28590497bb79279f036946 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/), version 0.4a12 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xgboost/xgboost-0.4a13.tar.gz#md5=5f53d51e4305c679192b3cabda2b0dbe (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/), version 0.4a13 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xgboost (from versions: 0.4a12, 0.4a13)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\c_kazum\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_c_kazum...
No distributions matching the version for xgboost
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\c_kazum\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\c_kazum\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Users\c_kazum\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\c_kazum\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 322, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions matching the version for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions matching the version for xgboost
```

Comment: This question has been crossposted from [Kaggle "How to XGBoost in Python 3.4.3 | Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)"](https://www.kaggle.com/c/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/forums/t/16120/how-to-xgboost-in-python-3-4-3-anaconda-2-2-0-64-bit) where we have been helping diagnose it

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to answer but I would still go ahead and answer it for anyone who still has an issue with the installation. I followed the steps listed in 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13043/run-xgboost-from-windows-and-python
Their is a concise version of these steps at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/windows. I will summarize what I did below.

1) Download Visual Basic Studio. You can download the community edition at visual studio website. There is a "free visual studio button on the upper right corner"

2) Copy all content from the git hub repository of xgboost/tree/master/windows  and Open Visual studio existing project on Visual studio

3) There are a couple of drop down menus you need to select ( "Release" and "X64" and then select build --> build all from the upper menu. It should look something like the attached screenshot.

4) if you see the message ========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========, it is all good

5) Browse to python-packages folder where the setup file for XGB resides and run the install command 'python setup.py install'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Generally, link only answers are frowned upon. It's better to summarise the content from the link in case the links dies of it's content changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is an xgboost issue, not an Anaconda issue as you originally tagged (I don't use Anaconda but I got this too).

EDIT: from your updates, your breakage is caused by 32-bit msys somewhere on your path, whereas you have a 64-bit install of Python. Mine and all other people's reported breakage since Aug 25 was the 0.4a12/3 prereleases:

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER - Based on the limited information you provided (here, as opposed to on the Kaggle thread) and no verbose fail logs:
Apparently the [latest versions of xgboost on pypi, 0.4a12 and 0.4a13](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xgboost/) are both pre-releases, which pip will not use by default, unless you do `pip install --pre xgboost`.

I found this all out by digging around with `pip install -v xgboost`, which shows helpful verbose information on why an attempted install failed (below); then use `pip help` and `pip install -h` to see all install options:

```
pip install -v xgboost Downloading/unpacking xgboost   Ignoring link
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xgboost/xgboost-0.4a12.tar.gz#md5=4d768e034a28590497bb79279f036946
(from https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/), version 0.4a12 is a
pre-release (use --pre to allow).   Ignoring link
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xgboost/xgboost-0.4a13.tar.gz#md5=5f53d51e4305c679192b3cabda2b0dbe
(from https://pypi.python.org/simple/xgboost/), version 0.4a13 is a
pre-release (use --pre to allow).
```

Then `pip install -h` tells you:

```
Install Options:
  -e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode ...
  ...
  --pre                       Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.
```

And finally:

```
pip install --pre xgboost
```

(PS xgboost maintainers made [a recent change in Aug 2015](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/commit/f4a5a8b6cd28fa9bcf9ed375b50a39220f06820e))

Comment: I use pip install --pre xgboost but still  no luck and I am getting error similar to this thread. https://www.kaggle.com/c/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/forums/t/16120/how-to-xgboost-in-python-3-4-3-anaconda-2-2-0-64-bit/90409

Comment: I was saying do **`pip install -v xgboost` to see the verbose reason for failure, then post it** as part of your question. Knowing the exact reason for failure should solve/help solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Heres the screen dump for using pip install -v xgboost

Comment: The screen dump is too big to add in the comment box...? However, I follow the instruction on the below link and build the package on the window box and it works !!! https://www.kaggle.com/c/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/forums/t/16120/how-to-xgboost-in-python-3-4-3-anaconda-2-2-0-64-bit/91223#post91223

Comment: Ok so the root-cause issue is your copy of MinGW/msys was 32-bit not 64-bit. However that thread is still unclear as to the **solution**. Please spell out the solution and post it here as answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-5
$ env CC=gcc CXX=g++
$ pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked for me (Mac OS)
Follow steps below in command prompt:

1. run whole command below "/bin......install.sh) "

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Note: check this for above command(https://brew.sh/)

2. brew install libomp
3. pip3 install xgboost