# How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, machine-learning, xgboost

http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

On the homepage of xgboost(above link), it says:
To install XGBoost, do the following steps:

1. You need to run `make` in the root directory of the project
2. In the python-package directory run

   python setup.py install

However, when I did it, for step 1 the following error appear:
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
 spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

then I skip step1 and did step 2 directly, another error appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
  File "xgboost/libpath.py", line 44, in find_lib_path
    'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
__builtin__.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
```

Does anyone know how to install xgboost for python on Windows10 platform? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found most upvoted answer easier than the accepted answer.
Just commenting here so that people save some time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I installed XGBoost successfully in Windows 8 64bit, Python 2.7 with Visual Studio 2013 (don't need mingw64)

**Updated 15/02/2017**

With newer version of XGBoost, here are my steps

**Step 1.** Install cmake https://cmake.org/download/

Verify `cmake` have been installed successfully

```
$ cmake
Usage

cmake [options] <path-to-source>
cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
...
```

**Step 2.** Clone xgboost source

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost xgboost_dir
```

**Step 3.** Create Visual Studio Project

```
$ cd xgboost_dir
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
```

**Step 4.** Build Visual Studio 2013 project

- Open file `xgboost_dir/build/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` with Visual Studio 2013
- In Visual Studio 2013, open `BUILD > Configuration Manager...`

  - choose Release in Active solution configuration
  - choose x64 in Active solution platform
- Click BUILD > Build Solution (Ctrl + Shift +B)

After build solution, two new files `libxgboost.dll` and `xgboost.exe` are created in folder `xgboost_dir/lib`

**Step 5.** Build python package

- Copy file `libxgboost.dll` to `xgboost_dir/python-package`
- Change directory to `xgboost_dir/python-package` folder
- Run command `python setup.py install`

Verify xgboost have been installed successfully

```
$ python -c "import xgboost"
```

**Old Answer**

Here are my steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
2. git checkout 9bc3d16
3. Open project in `xgboost/windows` with Visual Studio 2013
4. In Visual Studio 2013, open `BUILD > Configuration Manager...`,

   - choose `Release` in `Active solution configuration`
   - choose `x64` in `Active solution platform`
5. Rebuild `xgboost`, `xgboost_wrapper`
6. Copy all file in `xgboost/windows/x64/Release` folder to `xgboost/wrapper`
7. Go to `xgboost/python-package`, run command `python setup.py install`
8. Check xgboost by running command `python -c "import xgboost"`

Comment: from the latest download I didn't find any ffolder called Windows. what is the name of the VB file?

Comment: thanks for mention that, I update step 2 for checking out to commit which contains folders for Windows. I hope it will help you

Comment: @PuneetMathur why did you said the New Answer is useless?

Comment: Windows Binary: http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/

Comment: This solution worked for me but with the following changes: 1) You need to pull in the submodules before CMake: `git submodule init`, `git submodule update`. 2) I compiled with CUDA and the `gpuxgboost` part would not compile with an "identifier `_Inf` undefined in device code error". I had to change line 430 of `param.h` from `infinity()` to `max()`. 3) Only `xgboost.dll` was made and wasn't called `libxgboost.dll`. 4) You don't need to copy the DLL to `python-package`.  You can leave the DLL in that directory so when you use the Python install script, it automatically takes it from `lib`.

Answer (score 171):

In case anyone's looking for a simpler solution that doesn't require compiling it yourself:

1. download xgboost whl file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (make sure to match your python version and system architecture, e.g. "xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" for python 3.5 on 64-bit machine)
2. open command prompt
3. `cd` to your Downloads folder (or wherever you saved the whl file)
4. `pip install xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` (or whatever your whl file is named)

If you find it won't install because of a missing dependency, download and install the dependency first and retry.

If it complains about access permissions, try opening your command prompt as Administrator and retry.

This gives you xgboost and the scikit-learn wrapper, and saves you from having to go through the pain of compiling it yourself. :)

Comment: Note: python3 only.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for Python 3.6 on win10 64 bits

Comment: Life couldn't have been easier than this. Was able to install and import xgboost in under 1 minute. Hats off to this solution.

Comment: It installs but then when you call the lib from python it says that VCOMP140.DLL is missing. And yes, the Visual Studio IS installed.

Comment: @Anton - the website has precompiled whl files for python 2.7...so while I haven't tried it, methinks it should work... https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost

Comment: It got installed, but when I try to `import xgboost`, I get the following error: `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`. This maybe because of the backslashes in Windows paths. I don't want to risk breaking anything by manually editing the paths of site package files. How do I fix it?

Comment: Wheel's architecture should match the Python's one. If you have Python x32 installed on Windows x64, you have to install xgboost compiled for win32

Answer (score 32):

Note that as of the most recent release the Microsoft Visual Studio instructions no longer seem to apply as this link returns a 404 error:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/windows

You can read more about the removal of the MSVC build from Tianqi Chen's comment [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/928#issuecomment-193065994).

So here's what I did to finish a 64-bit build on Windows:

1. Download and install MinGW-64:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
2. On the first screen of the install prompt make sure you set the Architecture to **x86_64** and the Threads to **win32**
3. I installed to C:\mingw64 (to avoid spaces in the file path) so I added this to my PATH environment variable:  C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin
4. I also noticed that the make utility that is included in bin\mingw64 is called **mingw32-make** so to simplify things I just renamed this to **make**
5. Open a Windows command prompt and type gcc.  You should see something like "fatal error: no input file"
6. Next type make.  You should see something like "No targets specified and no makefile found"
7. Type git.  If you don't have git, install it and add it to your
   PATH.

These should be all the tools you need to build the xgboost project.  To get the source code run these lines:

1. cd c:\
2. git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
3. cd xgboost
4. git submodule init
5. git submodule update
6. cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
7. make -j4

Note that I ran this part from a Cygwin shell.  If you are using the Windows command prompt you should be able to change cp to copy and arrive at the same result.  However, if the build fails on you for any reason I would recommend trying again using cygwin.

If the build finishes successfully, you should have a file called xgboost.exe located in the project root.  To install the Python package, do the following:

1. cd python-package
2. python setup.py install

Now you should be good to go.  Open up Python, and you can import the package with:

```
import xgboost as xgb
```

To test the installation, I went ahead and ran the basic_walkthrough.py file that was included in the demo/guide-python folder of the project and didn't get any errors.

Comment: The mingw-w64.exe has been banned on SourceForge :(

Comment: I've found this site providing a compressed version that can be used in windows when unzipped: [link](http://www.drangon.org/mingw/). Add it to %path% and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. I ran all the commands in windows command prompt. Had to run the cmd prompt as administrator, otherwise didn't work.

Comment: I've  tried to use minigw on 32 bit system, but failed cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/common/common.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [build/common/common.o] Error 1

How can I fix that?

Comment: I got an error in the last step. can you please help with this?
http://www.codesend.com/view/6a9dc578efb87380a6aaed6889d878d6/

Comment: The installation instructions are good, but I encountered two problems: 1) Company proxy didn't support MinGW installation. Solved this using the chocolatey.org package manager. 2) The Anaconda distribution for python has an outdated version of the libstdc++-6.dll located in C:/Anaconda/Scripts. Copy the latest version from the MinGW/Bin folder, and you're good to go.

Comment: I had some errors following these steps, but then I red that there is an issue with the last version of xgboost. The solution is to checkout to 9a48a40 as explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773939/error-happens-when-install-xgboost4-0-in-windows7-python2-7

Comment: In addition, you may need to add " #include <cmath> " in src/tree/param.h to avoid new errors!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Worked for me with following caveats: 1) installing MingW64: make sure to choose x86_64. 2) DO NOT rename make-- leave it as C:/mingw64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe. 3) run in cygwin shell, and invoke with C:/mingw64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4. The reason not to rename make is, if your cygwin already has make and gcc, it may (depending on how you add your mingw64/bin path) still go to cygwin make+gcc instead of mingw64 make+gcc, which will cause problems starting with looking for a nonexistent execinfo.h file (and continuing with many more...)

Answer (score 10):

**I just installed xgboost both for my python 2.7 and python 3.5, anaconda, 64bit machine and 64 bit python.**

**both VERY simple, NO VS2013 or git required.**

I think it works for normal python, too.

If you use python 3.5:

1: download the package [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), the version depends on your python version, python3.5 or python 3.6, 32bit or 64bit.

2: use the command window, use cd to make the download folder as your pwd, then use

```
pip install filename.whl
```

OK, finished.
For more detailed steps, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811079/5918696)

if you use python 2.7, **you do NOT need to download the VS2013 to build it yourself, because I have built it, you can download the file I built and install it directly**

1: Download it [here by google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6HXvVF1p1HWcTdwZ2dGYkVyZG8/view?usp=sharing)

2: Download it, decompress it, paste it here:

"your python path\Lib\site-packages"

Then you should have something look like this:

[image]

3: In python-package folder showed above, use cmd window, cd there and run

```
python setup.py install
```

use this code

```
 import xgboost
```

in your python to check whether you have installed mingw-64 or not, No error information means you have installed the mingw-64 and you are finished.

If there are error information

"WindowsError: [Error 126] "

That means you have not installed mingw-64, and you have one more step to go.

Download the mingw-64 here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Choose x86_64 instead of the default "i686" when you installed the mingw-64,
then add "your install path\x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin;" to your PATH, it should be something like this:

"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin;"

(this is mine).

Don't forget the ";" in the PATH.

Then you are finished,you can use

```
import xgboost
```

in your python to check that, Yeah!

PS: if you don't know how to add path, just google it to get solutions. Don't worry, it's very simple.

Comment: I meet an WindowsError: [Error 193], it's the same as WindowsError: [Error 126] ?

Comment: @JohnnyWong Its not, see more here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374710/windowserror-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-in-python

Answer (score 5):

If You are installing XGBoost for a particular Project and You are using Pycahrm then you need to follow the procedures given below:

1. Download `xgboost‑0.72‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` from [Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost) (as I am using Python 3.6 if you use different version of Python like 2.7 then you need to install `xgboost‑0.72‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl`).
2. Copy the to your Project Interpreter directory. You can find the directory of Project Interpreter by clicking `File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter` from Pycharm.
3. Open Command Prompt. Go to directory to you Project Interpreter from cmd. Write the following command: `pip install xgboost-0.72-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 2):

On windows 10 , with python 3.6, below command worked.

From Anaconda Prompt, below command can be used directly. The screenshot is attached as proof.
pip install xgboost
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After build the c++ version, copy the release dll and lib files in ../windows/x64/Release/..(if you build x64 version) to ../wrapper/ then run python setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps listed in https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13043/run-xgboost-from-windows-and-python. I will summarize what I did below.

1) Download Visual Basic Studio. You can download the community edition at visual studio website. There is a "free visual studio button on the upper right corner"

2) Copy all content from the git hub repository of xgboost/tree/master/windows and Open Visual studio existing project on Visual studio

3) There are a couple of drop down menus you need to select ( "Release" and "X64" and then select build --> build all from the upper menu. It should look something like the attached screenshot.

4) if you see the message ========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========, it is all good

5) Browse to python-packages folder where the setup file for XGB resides and run the install command 'python setup.py install'.

You can find a similar thread at [Install xgboost under python with 32-bit msys failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258463/install-xgboost-under-python-with-32-bit-msys-failing/34868905#34868905)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can install xGBoost using either Visual Studio or minGW. Since, the official xgboost website says that MSVC build is not yet updated, I tried using mingw64.
I am running xgboost (python package) on my win7 x64. Steps I followed were:

1) Follow *Disco4Ever*'s steps for ming64 installation (mentioned above in the answers).

2) Install Git for windows. [windows download link](https://git-scm.com/download/win). This will also install Git Bash. Add *git-installation-directory*\cmd to your system environment variable PATH list.

3) Now clone xGBoost in desired location. Type the following in cmd:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
make -j4
```

4) In xgboost's root directory there should be a shell script named "build". Open it. It'll open up a Git Bash and start building. After building, xgboost.exe file will be created.

5) Now install python package :

```
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```

You can test by importing xgboost in python.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the solution by Disco4ever for those attempting to build on 32bit Windows machines.

After doing step 6 and creating a config.mk file you need to go into this file and edit the following lines to remove the -m64 flag

```
export CXX=g++ -m64
export CC=gcc -m64
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding "git checkout 9a48a40" to Disco4Ever's solution above worked for me:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git checkout 9a48a40
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

This was originally posted by Cortajarena here:
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1267

Also, for what it's worth, I originally had 32 bit Python running on my 64 bit machine and I had to upload 64 bit Python for XGBoost to work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to disco4ever answer. I was trying to build xgboost for Python Anaconda environment in my windows 10 64 bit machine. Used Git, mingw64 and basic windows cmd.

Everthing worked for me till the copy step: cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk, as I was using windows cmd I modified it to copy **c:\xgboost\make\mingw64.mk c:\xgboost\config.mk**

when I proceeded to the next step : make -j4, I got error that build failed. At this stage after so much frustration just tired something different by clicking on build.sh (shell script). It started executing and auto finished.

Then I executed the same step make -j4, to my awe build was successful. I have seen the most awaited xgboost.exe file in my xgboost folder.

I then proceeded with further steps and executed python setup.py install. finally everything installed perfectly. Then I went to my spyder and checked whether it is working or not. But I was one step away to my happiness because I was still seeing the import error.

Closed all command prompts (Anaconda, Git bash, Windows CMD, cygwin terminal) then again opened spyder and typed 'import xgboost'. SUCCESS, No ERROR.

Once again thank you for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It took a whole day, but I successfully installed xgboost on windows 7 64-bit box using [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download)  **with OpenMP enabled, instead of MingW** following this link - http://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [very helpful link with important points](https://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/) to pay attention to during installation. It's very important to install "openmp". Otherwise you'll get error message.

The link provides a step by step instruction for installing. Here's some quote:

> Building Xgboost
>
> To be fair, there is nothing wrong about the official guide for
>   installing xgboost on Windows. But still, I’d love to stress several
>   points here to save your time.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost  
cd xgboost  
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8myex4bnuzcp03/Makefile_win?dl=1
cp Makefile_win Makefile
cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
mingw32-make
```

> Makefile_win is a modified version (thanks to Zhou Xiyou) of the
>   original Makefile to suit the building process on Windows. You can
>   wget it or download it here. Be sure to use a UNIX shell for thi
>   because Windows CMD has issue with mkdir -p command. Git Bash is
>   recommended. Be sure to use --recursive option with git clone. Be sure
>   to use a proper MinGW. TDM-GCC is recommended. Note that by default it
>   wouldn’t install OpenMP for you. You need to specifiy it otherwise the
>   building would fail.

Another helpful link is the official procedure: [official guide](http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a small workaround to Disco4ever 's solution.

For me I was unable to perform cloning in cygwin. So the workaround is perform it in command prompt in windows and do the rest of the task in cygwin.

Use cd c:\xgboost in the 3rd line to make it work in cygwin. So the updated last part is like this.

```
cd c:\
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd c:\xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
make -j4
```

And after installation is complete you can uninstall git and cygwin but xgboost and mingw64 must be kept as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Note that: before "make -j4" use gcc -v to check your gcc version.

As to me, My environment is win10 + anaconda(python 2.7), when I run make -j4. It shows std::mutex error. After I use gcc- v It echo gcc4.7(anaconda's default gcc).After I choose my gcc to mingw64's 6.2 gcc ,then it works.

Finally, I use "/d/Anaconda2/python.exe setup.py install" install xgboost python packet.

Answer (score 0):

You can install XGBoost using following 3 steps:

1. Gather information of your system (python version and system architecture - 32 bit or 64 bit)
2. download related .whl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

e.g. if your python version is 3.7 and windows is 32 bit, then suitable file is:

> xgboost‑0.72‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl

3. run pip install yourdownloadedfile.whl

You can also find detailed steps [here](http://webindream.com/how-to-install-xgboost-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

I use Jupyter notebook and I found a really simple way to install XGBoost within Anaconda:

1. Install Anaconda
2. Open Anaconda Navigator
3. In Environments, update the index and search for xgboost (in not-installed)
4. Pick libxgboost and py-xgboost and click 'Apply'

Done