# Compiling Xgboost library for python in 32 bit system

Tags: python, makefile, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to follow the instruction below on my 32 bit Windows, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform):

1. cd c:\
2. git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
3. cd xgboost
4. git submodule init
5. git submodule update
6. cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
7. make -j4

But I get such error:

```
$ cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk; make -j4
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0  -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0  -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0  -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fopenmp -MM -MT build/common/common.o src/common/common.cc >build/common/common.d
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0  -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api_error.o src/c_api/c_api_error.cc >build/c_api/c_api_error.d
cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/logging.o' failed
mingw32-make:  [build/logging.o] Error 1
mingw32-make:  Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/common/common.o' failed
mingw32-make:  [build/common/common.o] Error 1
cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/learner.o' failed
mingw32-make:  [build/learner.o] Error 1
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/c_api/c_api_error.o' failed
mingw32-make:  [build/c_api/c_api_error.o] Error 1
```

How can I make it to work on my 32 bit machine?
Issue on [github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/994)

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I'm having the same problem now.

Comment: @chengvt have you tried this instruction http://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/ ? I failed to install on 32 bit. Which type of windows do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the problem now. The mingw32 path is set is rtools which seems to not support 64 bit. And despite changing the path, git bash requires restarting for the new path to be recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use whl packages: pip install some-package.whl

Xgboost you can download here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/