# Python module found when running from shell, but not from IPython

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, xgboost

I installed Anaconda python on Windows 7, and then installed the xgboost package manually using the instructions here: [How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/35119904#35119904) (It did not get installed under anaconda, but in a separate directory)

I put the following in test.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:<path>/xgboost/python-package')
import xgboost
```

When from a command line (say, from cygwin) the import works fine.
But, if I use the Spyder IDE or IPython that came with Anaconda, I get

```
WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-afdaff4619ce> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import xgboost

    C:...\xgboost\python-package\xgboost\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 import os
     10
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit

C:...\xgboost\python-package\xgboost\core.py in <module>()
     81
     82 # load the XGBoost library globally
---> 83 _LIB = _load_lib()
     84
     85 def _check_call(ret):

C:...\xgboost\python-package\xgboost\core.py in _load_lib()
     75     if len(lib_path) == 0:
     76         return None
---> 77     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
     78     lib.XGBGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
     79     return lib

C:...\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.pyc in Lo adLibrary(self, name)
    441
    442     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 443         return self._dlltype(name)
    444
    445 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

C:...continuum\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.pyc in __ init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363
    364         if handle is None:
--> 365             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    366         else:
    367             self._handle = handle

WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I've checked sys.executable, and I'm running the same python in shell and IPython. printing sys.path shows that the proper location is part of the path in both cases. Any idea what is happening? I'd really like to be able to use the IDE.

Comment: Yuck, don't munge `sys.path` like that.  Better you use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: What is `sys.executable` when running Python from a command prompt and from IPython?

Comment: Yes, I understand using PYTHONPATH is the preferred way to do this... I just wanted to take that piece out of the equation, for this example.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? Stuck with same problem for long