# Windows xgboost error

Tags: python, import, xgboost

It was a pain just to install xgboost library, but now other mistake happened on Windows 8.1 64-bit

```
import xgboost as xgb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Пашка/PycharmProjects/kaggler bank santander/1.py", line 12, in <module>
    import xgboost as xgb
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py3.4.egg\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py3.4.egg\xgboost\core.py", line 83, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py3.4.egg\xgboost\core.py", line 77, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What can be done? I think it is because of how .py files associated in Windows I guess

Comment: Seems like the installation of xgb is not correctly done. Any errors encountered during installation? You may want to use this instructions for installation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/35119904#35119904

Comment: @Deepish Basically, I followed that instruction, no mistake seemed to appear. After that, I tried to use pre-compiled library when I just put it to my site-packages folder. Its still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that probably the simplest (most painless) way to install `xgboost` can be found here:

https://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/ (Much thanks to the author!)

I downloaded TDM-GCC as recommended by the author prior to following their instructions.

Also, I had similar issues installing `xgboost` on 32-bit Python but am having no issues using 64-bit Python.

Note: I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: You were right, the problem was with 64 bit. Now it is finally working

Answer (score 1):

Building on Windows has recently become much simpler:

## Install CMake

CMake can be downloaded from here: https://cmake.org/download/

I downloaded the 64 bit zip file: https://cmake.org/files/v3.6/cmake-3.6.2-win64-x64.zip and unzipped it to c:\dev\cmake-3.6.2-win64-x64.

## Build XGBoost

To build XGBoost follow these steps:

- git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
- cd xgboost
- git submodule init
- git submodule update
- mkdir build
- cd build
- C:\dev\cmake-3.6.2-win64-x64\bin\cmake.exe .. -G”Visual Studio 14 2015 * Win64″
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe /t:Clean,Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release xgboost.sln

## Or Just Download the Binaries (x64)

Unofficial (mine) Nightly builds [here](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/).