# Changing the Anaconda installation directory

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, xgboost

I'm using Anaconda and Windows 10 and have to install the XGBoost package. I managed to do it for python using this helpful article (http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/) and tried to install it in Anaconda according to this question ([Windows xgboost error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519898/windows-xgboost-error)). Somehow, it appeared that the command 'python setup.py install' tries to change a wrong directory (C:\Program Files... instead of D:\Anaconda...) How can I change the installation directory so that changes are made where they should?

Comment: If you run "python" anywhere in  your command shell, it will pick the one that is registered in the `path` variable of Windows. Have you checked if it's the right one (D:\Anaconda\...)?

Comment: can you post the output of the following command below? `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`

Comment: No, but the path that it picks (C:\Program Files\…) isn't registered in the path variable either

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe that is the directory it tries to change and the output of python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to activate the correct Anaconda in your console by executing the `activate` script in the appropriate folder, e.g.:

```
D:\Anaconda\Scripts\activate
```

You might have to slightly adjust the path to your installation. If this works, you'll see `(base)` in front of the next line in the command prompt. On my machine, I get this output:

```
C:\Users\felix>C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate

(base) C:\Users\felix>
```

After anaconda is activated, executing `python` should use the correct executable. You can verify this using the command I posted as a comment before:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Thanks very much, I've been trying to install XGBoost for the whole day and succeeded only after your answer)

Comment: Glad I could help! ;-)