# error happens when install xgboost4.0 in windows7, python2.7

Tags: python, git, installation, windows-7-x64, xgboost

Here is the process I tried to install xgboost:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
```

It was good until I ran the code in my git bash

```
 make -j4
```

It goes wrong:

```
    F:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:450:83: error: 'FILE* std::fopen(const char*, const char*)' should have been declared inside 'std'
   FILE *fopen64(const char * __restrict__ filename,const char * __restrict__  mode);
                                                                                   ^
F:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:450:83: error: 'FILE* std::fopen(const char*, const char*)' conflicts with a previous declaration
F:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:449:17: note: previous declaration 'FILE* fopen(const char*, const char*)'
   FILE *__cdecl fopen(const char * __restrict__ _Filename,const char * __restrict__ _Mode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
                 ^
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/c_api/c_api_error.o' failed
make: *** [build/c_api/c_api_error.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from dmlc-core/include/dmlc/registry.h:14:0,
                 from include/xgboost/./gbm.h:11,
                 from include/xgboost/learner.h:16,
                 from src/learner.cc:8:
dmlc-core/include/dmlc/./parameter.h:254:43: warning: 'xgboost::__make__LearnerModelParamParamManager__' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   static ::dmlc::parameter::ParamManager &__make__ ## PType ## ParamManager__ = \
                                           ^
src/learner.cc:107:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DMLC_REGISTER_PARAMETER'
 DMLC_REGISTER_PARAMETER(LearnerModelParam);
 ^
dmlc-core/include/dmlc/./parameter.h:254:43: warning: 'xgboost::__make__LearnerTrainParamParamManager__' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   static ::dmlc::parameter::ParamManager &__make__ ## PType ## ParamManager__ = \
                                           ^
src/learner.cc:108:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DMLC_REGISTER_PARAMETER'
 DMLC_REGISTER_PARAMETER(LearnerTrainParam);
```

I find some reference which shows the reason may be related to the difference between the windows system and Unix, but it is beyond my konwledge.

I installed `mingw64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue raised on the [github page](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1267).

After cloning, checkout to version `9a48a40` then repeat the steps you performed above. I was having the same issue, and this worked for me.

Quoting from the link:

> Fixed, just clone repo and then checkout to 9a48a40 until they fix it,
>   something in the last commits must have screwed up the compilation:
>
> ```
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
> cd xgboost
> git checkout 9a48a40
> git submodule init
> git submodule update
> ```

Comment: Thanks~It is a new bug just fixed a few hours ago.