# Missing /bin folder from MinGW-W64 installation

Tags: python, windows, git, xgboost

Right now I am working through [this walk-through](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en) on how to get the xgboost package for python. I'm running on Windows 10.

I've just added `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin` to my path variable, as the instructions dictate. However, when I actually visit using windows explorer `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0` I see:

[image]

No `mingw64\bin` folder in sight. This seems to be an issue, because when I try to move on to the next step and double check if the make is findable in the Git Shell, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\thomasjp\Documents\GitHub> which mingw32-make

/usr/bin/which: no mingw32-make in (/cmd:/usr/bin:/usr/share/git-tfs:/c/Users/thomasjp/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/03NZLAC2.ADB/NNC33V77.BDA/gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0001_cbe40ecbe3e419d4:/c/Users/thomasjp/AppData/Local/GitHub/lfs-amd64_1.2.0:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/command:/c/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/Users/thomasjp/Miniconda3:/c/Users/thomasjp/Miniconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/thomasjp/Miniconda3/Library/bin:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin)
```

Which is basically a long way of saying that `mingw32-make` doesn't exist. Why is this? What should I do?

Feel free to ask more questions/suggest edits if my questions aren't clear or reproducible.

Comment: Been a while since I bothered building anything for Windows, but I think you need to install some packages through MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to do the same walk-through but with the [tdm-gcc as mingw](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) and it worked

I suggest you look at the more general answer of [Disco4Ever here, on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35119904/2269733) on how to install XGBoost on windows for python

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/
Go to this site and install mingw file manager

Step 2 - Then, install all the from the file manager or based on your preference.

Step 3 - Now, go to the File explorer in your system and see that you have bin folder in mingw.

I hope the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The folder where minGW is installed can't have spaces try removing the space from
"Program files" or use programfiles.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you haven't downloaded Mingw-Minimalist GNU for windows, and have downloaded a zip called Mingw-w64...