# ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core while installing XGBoost in Windows/Python

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost

I am planning to install the XGBoost package in Python for Windows. After following the instructions mentioned here ([How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/35119904#35119904)), I am facing issues during the last step (python setup.py install).

```
    $ python setup.py install --user
Install libxgboost from: ['..\\lib\\xgboost.dll']
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to xgboost.egg-info\requires.txt
writing xgboost.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to xgboost.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to xgboost.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'xgboost.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'xgboost\include'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'xgboost\src'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'xgboost\make'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'xgboost\rabit'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'xgboost\lib'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'xgboost\dmlc-core'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.o' found anywhere in distribut                                                                                                                ion
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribut                                                                                                                ion
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distrib                                                                                                                ution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distrib                                                                                                                ution
writing manifest file 'xgboost.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\build-python.sh -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\callback.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\compat.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\core.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\libpath.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\plotting.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\rabit.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\sklearn.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\training.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\VERSION -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
copying build\lib\xgboost\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\callback.py to callback.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\compat.py to compat.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\core.py to core.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\libpath.py to libpath.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\plotting.py to plotting.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\rabit.py to rabit.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\sklearn.py to sklearn.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\training.py to training.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
installing package data to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_data
copying ..\lib\xgboost.dll -> build\bdist.win32\egg\xgboost
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info\not-zip-safe -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
creating 'dist\xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg
creating c:\users\mishraji\appdata\roaming\python\python27\site-packages\xgboost                                                                                                                -0.6-py2.7.egg
Extracting xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg to c:\users\mishraji\appdata\roaming\python\pyt                                                                                                                hon27\site-packages
Adding xgboost 0.6 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\mishraji\appdata\roaming\python\python27\site-packages\xgboos                                                                                                                t-0.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for xgboost==0.6
Searching for scipy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/52/67/d9ef9b5058d4a9e3f0ae641ec1517                                                                                                                90622cbeb37f157de5773358e2bf3da/scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz#md5=6b4d91b62f1926282b127194                                                                                                                a06b72b3
Best match: scipy 0.19.1
Processing scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\mishraji\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cxrtxb\scipy-0.19.1\se                                                                                                                tup.cfg
Running scipy-0.19.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\mishraji\appdata\                                                                                                                local\temp\easy_install-cxrtxb\scipy-0.19.1\egg-dist-tmp-hya72r
c:\users\mishraji\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cxrtxb\scipy-0.19.1\setup.py:3                                                                                                                23: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cyt                                                                                                                hon sources and expanding templates
  warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 42, in <module>
    url='https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, i                                                                                                                n run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 117,                                                                                                                 in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 410, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 646, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 697, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 742, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 850, in r                                                                                                                esolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1122, in                                                                                                                 best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in                                                                                                                 obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 665, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 695, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 876, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 1115, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line                                                                                                                 1101, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 251, in run_s                                                                                                                etup
    raise
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup                                                                                                                _context
    yield
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 169, in save_                                                                                                                modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 144, in resum                                                                                                                e
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in save_                                                                                                                modules
    yield saved
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup                                                                                                                _context
    yield
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 248, in run_s                                                                                                                etup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 278, in run
    return func()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in runne                                                                                                                r
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _execf                                                                                                                ile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "c:\users\mishraji\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cxrtxb\scipy-0.19.1\se                                                                                                                tup.py", line 416, in <module>

  File "c:\users\mishraji\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cxrtxb\scipy-0.19.1\se                                                                                                                tup.py", line 396, in setup_package

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
```

However, when I import the package in python, it works without any issue.

```
import numpy.distutils.core as np
```

Comment: Are they running with the same python version? Also, try installing scipy.

Comment: Scipy 0.19.0-1 is already installed. Yes, they are running with same Python version 2.7

Comment: Hi ColdSpped, you were right, I was using two versions of python. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occured because I had two python versions (v 2.7.13) and Enthought Canopy (Python 2.7.11). As Python 2.7.11 already had Numpy package, xgboost got installed successfully.

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in a Docker, installing numpy first worked:

```
RUN pip install numpy==1.8.1
RUN pip install scikit-fmm==0.0.9
```