# Error installing XGBoost on win 10

Tags: xgboost

I'm trying to install xgboost on win 10 but got this error :

```
C:\Users\Philippe>pip install xgboost
Collecting xgboost
  Using cached xgboost-0.6a2.tar.gz
No files/directories in C:\Users\Philippe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tnihtd1j\xgboost\pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Look this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811079/12568621

in summary:

- download xgboost whl
- open prompt
- cd to folder where saved the file.
- pip install "name-saved-file"

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

1. Open a jupyter notebook.
2. Type this in the cell and run
    `!pip install xgboost`

   [My shell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwwja.png)

Comment: Please put your code into the question, not linked as an image. Otherwise if the host is removed, this answer is not helpful anymore.