# xgboost pckage for python 3.6

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying in install xgboost0.72 in window and python 3.6.5
It shows me the following error:

> xgboost-0.72-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Can anyone help me out which version of xgboost is compatible with python 3.6.5.
Thanks
zep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing:

```
pip install xgboost
```

It works for me.

Or try this:

1. download xgboost whl file from [here][1] (make sure to match your python version and system architecture, e.g. "xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" for python 3.5 on 64-bit machine)
2. open command prompt
3. `cd` to your Downloads folder (or wherever you saved the whl file)
4. `pip install xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` (or whatever your whl file is named)

Source :[How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/39811079#39811079)

Comment: You seem to have missed the link. Can you please check it where you mentioned `here`