# xgboost-...whl is not supported wheel in this platform

Tags: python-3.x, pip, xgboost

Similar to:
[whl is not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817359/whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)
[xgboost pckage for python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455884/xgboost-pckage-for-python-3-6)

But both didn't work for me. 
I need to install xgboost on machine without internet.

I downloaded xgboost-0.81-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl file from https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/#files

My environment:

- Windows X64
- Python 3.7.0
- pip 19.0.1

I got an error:
[image]

Same with "xgboost-0.81-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" from this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost)

I tried in similar way install "scikit_learn-0.20.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl" and everything went well.

I also tried

```
pip download xgboost -d "C:\USers...\XGBoost"
tar cvfz xgboost.tgz XGBoost
```

but I have error:

"tar" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Even i m facing same issue. python 3.8 on windows 64 bit trying to install below not working
C:\Users\ananthi\Downloads>pip install xgboost-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: xgboost-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried …`win32.whl` and everything went well.

You have 32-bit Python. With it you cannot install 64-bit wheel (`amd64.whl`). Download 32-bit wheel.

Or replace your Python with 64-bit Python and reinstall all packages.

Comment: you are right. How can I check python bit version using command prompt?

Comment: Version: `python --version`, 32/64 bitness: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anaconda Powershell Prompt(menu->Anaconda->Anaconda Powershell Prompt) to install xgboost

command:**pip install xgboost**

hope it helps you